# Unable to deploy SSAS project. reason : The syntax of 'Birthdate' is incorrect

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, msbi

I created the following Dax expression to calculate the Age

```
Age :=
VAR Birthdate = DIM_CUSTOMER[DATEOFBIRTH]
VAR ThisDay =TODAY ()
VAR IntBirthdate =
    YEAR ( Birthdate ) * 10000
        + MONTH ( Birthdate ) * 100
        + DAY ( Birthdate )
VAR IntThisDay =
    YEAR ( ThisDay ) * 10000
        + MONTH ( ThisDay ) * 100
        + DAY ( ThisDay )
VAR Age =
    QUOTIENT ( IntThisDay - IntBirthdate; 10000 )
VAR CheckedAge =
    DIVIDE ( Age; NOT ISBLANK ( Birthdate ) )
RETURN
    CheckedAge
```

[image: The result of Age DAX expression in SSAS]

It seems that it work perfectly
But, when I tried to Deploy the project I got the following ERROR

"Impossible de déployer les métadonnées. Raison : La syntaxe pour 'Birthdate' est incorrecte.
La colonne calculée 'DIM_CUSTOMER[Age]' contient une erreur de syntaxe. Entrez une formule valide."

[image: the ERROR screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really weird age calculation. I don't understand why you're dividing by a date for `CheckedAge`.

Why not something like this?

```
 Age := DATEDIFF ( DIM_CUSTOMER[DATEOFBIRTH], TODAY (), YEAR )
```

or

```
Age := DIVIDE ( DATEDIFF ( DIM_CUSTOMER[DATEOFBIRTH], TODAY (), DAY ), 365.25 )
```

Comment: Hi @Alexis, first of all i would like to thank you for your reply.
when i tried your method i managed to deploy the project, but now the problem is in power bi i couldn't use the Age column because i've had the following Error Message:
Calculated column referenced by the query 'DIM_CUSTOMER' [Age] which contains no data, because an error appears in its expression.